# A typical tech stack using vowpal wabbit?

Tags: c++, apache-spark, machine-learning, vowpalwabbit

Hi I want to see an example tech stack where vowpal wabbit is used.

This can be actual application which people are using or an imaginary one which illustrates how VW fits.

We are currently facing a common legacy code problem. Our back end is a collection of web services implemented in C++ using relational DB and Front end is Javascript based web app build on top of those webservices.

Now We want to extend our backend to provide some analytics services which uses machine learning functionality. Having seen around, I quite liked Apache Spark + ML + GraphX as graph already heavily features in our server logic. But the problem is they are not C++. Though they can be made to integrate with it, but as we will be writing lot of our own stuff, We will have to write non-C++/Javascript code, which is currently not under consideration.

Vowpal Wabbit is another candidate that meets our criteria but I am not sure how it would fit over-all right from raw-data storage to application logic. Hence the question.

Comment: If I understand, you want to be able to call the ML library directly from your C++ code. Having worked on a lot of data oriented solutions, I can tell that usually, people prefer having a modular approach and APIs for the communication that are independant of the languages used (which to it extremes gives you microservices). I used VW in a node.js app, and I simply built a wrapper around a shell command call. Sometimes I go for REST API, sometimes I can use tools like zeroMQ, etc. But the idea is that I want to be able to change quickly libraries with minimal changes.

Answer (score 1):

As I recall VW could be built as static library (check examples in its ./library folder). And perhaps as dynamic library too. Thus it could be just incorporated in your legacy c++ app.

Answer (score 1):

Vowpal can be used as a library and the source code include examples of using the API in C++.  We are using it in an iOS application with no problems.  The only slight oddity is the need to use boost::program_options to initialize the library and various methods.  If you were motivated, you could further develop the API to accept arguments. The maintainers seem to actively encourage the development of patches and features.